# Can we use existing payment process - wrapped in an App Wrapper for Apple App Store?

Tags: ios

We have an existing working mobile website with full payment gateway integration.

This is for booking of sports sessions. The mobile site goes to a 3rd party website for payment processing then returns to our mobile site.

We simply want to wrap the existing website into an App wrapper using Phonegap or similar, and hopefully keep the existing payment workflow.

Will our app get rejected by the Apple App store? On App Store review guidelines it says:

11.13 - Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "Buy" button that goes to a website to purchase a digital book, will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Apple distinguishes between **digital** and **non-digital** products.

If you are selling **digital** products (like content or additional functionality in your app) you must use Apple's In-App purchase process and you are not allowed to use other ways of payment.

However if you are selling **real-world** goods and services you are not even allowed to use Apple's In-App Purchase process. You have to use another way of payment.

So you should be fine.